# Clojure and maven ... can't read a resource data file

Tags: maven, clojure

I have this in my maven pom.xml file of an Clojure application:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/clojure/com/codenvy/example/clojure</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>test.fasta</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

and `(slurp "test.fasta")` in my Clojure code.

The Clojure file "App.clj" and the data file "test.fasta" files live in the directory

```
src/main/clojure/com/codenvy/example/clojure
```

But I always get an error:

```
...
[STDERR] Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.fasta (No such file or directory)
[STDERR]    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
[STDERR]    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$fn__8702.invoke(io.clj:229)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$fn__8615$G__8606__8622.invoke(io.clj:69)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$fn__8714.invoke(io.clj:258)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$fn__8615$G__8606__8622.invoke(io.clj:69)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$fn__8676.invoke(io.clj:165)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$fn__8628$G__8610__8635.invoke(io.clj:69)
[STDERR]    at clojure.java.io$reader.doInvoke(io.clj:102)
[STDERR]    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
[STDERR]    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
[STDERR]    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
[STDERR]    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
[STDERR]    at clojure.core$slurp.doInvoke(core.clj:6390)
[STDERR]    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
[STDERR]    at com.codenvy.example.clojure.App$_main.doInvoke(App.clj:35)
[STDERR]    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
[STDERR]    at com.codenvy.example.clojure.App.main(Unknown Source)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slurp` operates on relative/absolute paths without heeding the classpath. But you can still slurp from there using `clojure.java.io/resource`:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(slurp (io/resource "test.fasta"))
```

Be aware that `io/resource` returns `nil` if the resource could not be found. You probably want to guard against that.